# MySQL tables, error #1064 & error #1068 Multiple primary key defined

Tags: sql, mysql, create-table, mysql-error-1064, mysql-error-1068

I have got errors when I tried to install the MySQL tables, error:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax"

and error:

> "#1068 - Multiple primary key defined "

This is the database:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
msg_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
message VARCHAR(200),
uid_fk INT(10),
ip VARCHAR(45),
created INT(10),
uploads VARCHAR(50),
profile_uid INT(10)

PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`),
KEY `uid_fk` (`uid_fk`)

);


CREATE TABLE comments (
com_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
comment VARCHAR(200),
msg_id_fk INT(10),
uid_fk INT(10),
ip VARCHAR(45),
created INT(10),

PRIMARY KEY (`com_id`),
KEY `msg_id_fk` (`msg_id_fk`),
KEY `uid_fk` (`uid_fk`)

);


CREATE TABLE likes (
like_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
msg_id_fk INT(10),
uid_fk INT(10),

PRIMARY KEY (`like_id`),
KEY `msg_id_fk` (`msg_id_fk`),
KEY `uid_fk` (`uid_fk`)

);


CREATE TABLE user_uploads (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
image_path VARCHAR(500),
uid_fk INT(10),

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `uid_fk` (`uid_fk`)

);


CREATE TABLE follow_user (
fid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
uid_fk INT(10),
following_uid INT(10),

PRIMARY KEY (`fid`),
KEY `uid_fk` (`uid_fk`)

);
```

these are the errors images:

[image]

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: If you define the `PRIMARY KEY` in the _column definition_ as in `fid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`, you cannot and need not redefine it via `PRIMARY KEY (col)` later in `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: I won't make it an answer cause I'm not sure, but I don't think you can give the same name to keys on different tables...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either use the inline syntax (`msg_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`) or declare it afterwards (`PRIMARY KEY (`com_id`)`), not both : they conflict.

Answer (score 0):

And the syntax error in the messages table is simply a missing comma at the end of the `profile_uid INT(10)` line.