# phpMyAdmin export issue

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1068

My shared host does not allow SSH access. I am trying to export a database using phpMyAdmin and import onto a new server. I keep getting this error and I am not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

```
Error
SQL query:
--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--
--
-- Indexes for table `EWRporta_blocks`
--
ALTER TABLE  `EWRporta_blocks` ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `block_id` ) ,
ADD KEY  `title` (  `title` ) ;
MySQL said: Documentation
#1068 - Multiple primary key defined
```

Comment: tried using command line ? It's safer and is just a line command. You may find many docs on them. It's faster too.

Comment: i do not have access on my shared host.

Comment: There is always some way. Ask  your host. Figure out to get the command line access.

Comment: There is similar problem posted & answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336162/1068-multiple-primary-key-defined-in-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696899/mysql-tables-error-1064-error-1068-multiple-primary-key-defined... see if this helps. It has an answer too!

Comment: @TheShadyOneHD if you have a problem with data *export*, ignore Apul Gupta's answer about dropping database and dropping tables, it was copied from a question where there was a problem with *import*. If you did what he suggests, it would delete your data.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Drop your primary keys before the export and add them back once you're done.

Comment: i think you need to remove your previous primary keys and try again. agree with @AlexTartan

Comment: Are you sure this problem is directly related to phpMyAdmin itself?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue multiple times, and modonoghue has one valid way of handling it by dropping your tables and completely recreating them.

## Problem & a General Solution

Basically what is happening is that you are trying to run INSERT statements that are inserting values into primary keys that already exist - thereby giving you an error of duplicate keys. The database has no clue how to handle having multiple entries with the same key, as SQL logic is based around every 'row' having a primary key that is completely unique.

What you **want** to do is to save all the values to your exported sql file, in a query that, when you import the file again, *deletes* all the existing values (assuming you want to restore it to a certain point and aren't worrying about data saved between your export date and your import date!) and *inserts* all the exported values ... or somehow else avoids trying to add a new entry with an existing key (see following).

## One method to export a specific database (TRUNCATE):

1. In other words, when you are using PHPMYADMIN to export your sql file, click "Custom - display all possible options".
2. Under "Format-Specific Options" **make sure** "structure and data" is selected (otherwise you may end up dropping your tables and not having the data to restore them with!!!)
3. Under "Data Creation Options" select "Truncate table before insert" -- this will delete all the existing data in the tables.

When you import, all the existing data will be deleted from each table (TRUNCATE) and all the exported data will be written back to the tables (INSERT) but the tables themselves won't be deleted (DROP).

## IGNORE vs TRUNCATE (Alternative Route)

You should be able to skip Step 3 above (TRUNCATE) and instead select the checkbox "Instead of INSERT Statements Use ..." "INSERT IGNORE statements"

Basically, "IGNORE" will just skip over duplicates in your exported data, and prevents you from having to delete your existing data. This is good if you want to just add back lost data, without deleting data that's been changed / added since the last export.

## Superuser (ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE)

There is also an INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... that allows you to tell the query exactly what to do if there is a duplicate key. This prevents you from just ignoring two entries with identical keys that may not be identical entries. It is more complicated to setup properly, however.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, drop and recreate the tables. In phpmyadmin, select the check box labeled "add DROP TABLE" when doing the export. Then the issue described should be resolved on import.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering suggests that there is an attempt to add a primary key to the EWRporta_blocks table, but the primary key already exists. This can happen if the table structure is not being handled correctly during the import process.

Here are a few steps you can take to resolve this issue:

Check the SQL Dump:
Open the SQL dump file that you are trying to import, and look for the section where the EWRporta_blocks table is defined. It should contain the code for creating the table and adding indexes. Ensure that there is no duplicate definition for the primary key.

Remove Duplicate Primary Key Definitions:
If you find that there are multiple primary key definitions for the EWRporta_blocks table, remove the duplicate ones. There should be only one primary key definition for each table.

Modify the Table Structure Manually:
If the SQL dump file contains incorrect or duplicate primary key definitions, you might need to manually modify the file before importing it. Remove any extra primary key definitions for the EWRporta_blocks table.

Import with phpMyAdmin:
When importing the SQL dump using phpMyAdmin, make sure to select the option to 'Disable foreign key checks' and 'Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION' if available. This can help in avoiding conflicts during the import process.

Check Database Compatibility:
Ensure that the version of MySQL or MariaDB on the new server is compatible with the SQL dump. Sometimes, differences in database versions can lead to compatibility issues.

Review Database Schema:
Take a look at the existing structure of the EWRporta_blocks table on the new server. Make sure that there are no conflicting primary key definitions in the table.

After making these adjustments, try importing the modified SQL dump file again. If the issue persists, there might be a need for further analysis of the SQL dump file and the structure of the destination database.

Answer (score -1):

Remove comment Generated by export tool

```
--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--
--
-- Indexes for table `EWRporta_blocks`
--
```

and try to execute query as follow only

ALTER TABLE  `EWRporta_blocks` ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `block_id` ) ,
ADD KEY  `title` (  `title` ) ;